# Diesel generator ground and protection devices

Tags: grounding, generator

I have a question about protection in a portable power system.

I am working on a project that is a moving truck with a generator on it. We should use the generator to feed some customers when the truck is moving.

The generator is a 3 phase with 5 wires (L1, L2, L3, N, PE). PE and N are not connected.

My question is what should I do to make sure the protection devices (MCB & RCCB) work correctly during faults in a power system like this.

My concern is that if one of the phases be connected to the chassis of the truck then the body is electrified but the protection devices and fuses will not work.

I will be thankful if anyone gives me a solution for when if one of the phases is connected to the chassis, the MCB works and break the circuit.

[image: picture of Circuit Breaker]
[image: picture of CB from beside to show the Auxiliary wires]

Answer (score 3):

This is a can of wyrms and really needs designing at a system level.

Common practise is to bond the Neutral and PE together and take the PE to the chassis, then do all the circuit protection after that bond.

This was a short to chassis will trip the breakers, and a short to chassis will also not (if the impedance is sufficiently low) produce a dangerous touch voltage on between the vehicle and the generating set.

Note that the generator PSC is largely derived by the sub transient reactance of the machine and not the more obvious supply impedance.

I highly recommend a shunt trip breaker with under frequency and phase imbalance relays somewhere in the system, lost neutrals get expensive fast if this is something like a carnival float.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and attention.
I have a question about the shunt trip breaker that you said.
If I can, I will post the picture of my breaker above. The breaker is ABB SACE TMAX T1C.
The question is that there are 2 wires beside of the breaker and there is a YO label on it.
can you explain to me what are those wires? and if I understand it correctly I can connect these wires to the chassis and the other one to the neutral, and with this action, if one of the phases be connected to the chassis, then the breaker will opened.

Comment: I meant that if these 2 wires be energized the breaker will work and will open the circuit, am I right?

Comment: That may well be the wires for a shunt trip coil, but that is NOT the way to use it. Seriously, find someone who understands the design of portable three phase power systems, this is not something anyone can really guide you thru on stack exchange. The shunt trip is for equipment protection not safety of life stuff.